# Mail Process 140% in Activity Monitor/1 IMAP Account/Random Problem

Tags: mail.app

A friend of mine is having some problems with his Mail Account. As stated in the title, the Mail process uses 140% of the CPU, as shown in Activity Monitor. It's a random error, it doesn't happen all the time, it happens about once a week. I believe he restarts the application to make it go away, as it slows down his computer, and the fan starts making a lot of noise.

He has:

- OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.4;
- Mail 6.5 (1508)/No plugin;
- 1 IMAP account;
- A few thousand emails between the inbox, sent and a few folders.

There isn't any problem with the mail server (apparently, and according to the logs).

I've checked his account parameters, they seem fine.

He can send/receive emails (He told me so, and I've checked by sending a mail from his account to his account).

Also:

- Mail's cache has been deleted;
- SSL is activated in Mail.

Here are some lines from Activity Monitor:

```
    +                         ! 2 -[IMAPMailboxSyncEngine _processResponsesWithMonitor:]  (in IMAP) + 538  [0x7fff8d7a2b95]
    +                         ! : 1 -[IMAPResponse responseType]  (in IMAP) + 15  [0x7fff8d7ac1af]
    +                         ! : 1 objc_msgSend  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 25  [0x7fff88ae9259]
    +                         ! 2 -[IMAPMailboxSyncEngine _processResponsesWithMonitor:]  (in IMAP) + 393,1057  
[0x7fff8d7a2b04,0x7fff8d7a2d9c]
    +                         ! 1 -[IMAPMailboxSyncEngine _processResponsesWithMonitor:]  (in IMAP) + 111  [0x7fff8d7a29ea]
    +                         ! : 1 +[IMAPFramework userAgent]  (in IMAP) + 72  [0x7fff8d79699b]
    +                         ! :   1 objc_sync_exit  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 23  [0x7fff88aed4e8]
    +                         ! :     1 id2data(objc_object*, usage)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 709  [0x7fff88afddc4]
    +                         ! 1 -[IMAPMailboxSyncEngine _processResponsesWithMonitor:]  (in IMAP) + 606  [0x7fff8d7a2bd9]
    +                         !   1 objc_msgSend  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 25  [0x7fff88ae9259]
    +                         1 -[IMAPMailboxSyncEngine _goWithMessages:]  (in IMAP) + 808  [0x7fff8d7a2520]
    +                         ! 1 -[IMAPMailboxSyncEngine _shouldContinueSyncingWithMonitor:]  (in IMAP) + 73  
[0x7fff8d7a2957]
    +                         !   1 -[ActivityMonitor error]  (in CoreMessage) + 1  [0x7fff89ce29fa]
    +                         1 -[IMAPMailboxSyncEngine _goWithMessages:]  (in IMAP) + 1057  [0x7fff8d7a2619]
    +                           1 -[IMAPMailboxSyncEngine isReset]  (in IMAP) + 1  [0x7fff8d79cd57]
```

...
...

> - !           : 548 -[IMAPClientOperation main]  (in IMAP) + 84 
>     [0x7fff8d77cae3]
>
>   - !           : | 547 -[IMAPGateway allowClientOperationThrough:]  (in IMAP) + 369  [0x7fff8d797fd4]
>   - !           : | + 546 -[IMAPGateway _allowClientOperationThrough:]  (in IMAP) + 1237  [0x7fff8d798501]
>   - !           : | + ! 546 -[IMAPConnection prepareAndExecuteOperation:outWrongState:]  (in IMAP) + 1247 
>       [0x7fff8d7859f5]
>   - !           : | + !   546 -[IMAPClientFetchOperation executeOnConnection:]  (in IMAP) + 26  [0x7fff8d778ee2]
>   - !           : | + !     546 -[IMAPConnection executeFetch:]  (in IMAP) + 44  [0x7fff8d78b3d1]
>   - !           : | + !       538 -[IMAPConnection _responseFromSendingOperation:]  (in IMAP) + 863  [0x7fff8d78ba87]
>   - !           : | + !       : 480 -[IMAPConnection _copyNextTaggedOrContinuationResponseForCommand:exists:]  (in IMAP) +  551  [0x7fff8d7867eb]
>   - !           : | + !       : | 472 -[IMAPConnection _copyNextServerResponse:]  (in IMAP) + 55  [0x7fff8d78657a]
>   - !           : | + !       : | + 281 -[IMAPResponse initWithConnection:error:]  (in IMAP) + 608  [0x7fff8d7af5f8]
>   - !           : | + !       : | + ! 270 response_without_tag  (in IMAP) + 237  [0x7fff8d7b166b]
>   - !           : | + !       : | + ! : 67 fetch_response  (in IMAP) + 2746  [0x7fff8d7b2b81]
>   - !           : | + !      : | + ! : | 44 createFlagsSet  (in IMAP) + 159  [0x7fff8d7b4897]

...
...

> - !           : | + !       : | + 137 -[IMAPResponse initWithConnection:error:]  (in IMAP) + 144  [0x7fff8d7af428]
>
>   - !           : | + !       : | + ! 129 -[IMAPConnection(MFPrivate) _readDataOfLength:intoData:error:]  (in IMAP) + 112   [0x7fff8d78ce14]
>   - !           : | + !       : | + ! : 126 -[IMAPConnection _readLineIntoData:error:]  (in IMAP) + 53  [0x7fff8d786486]
>   - !           : | + !       : | + ! : | 90 -[Connection _readLineIntoData:error:]  (in CoreMessage) + 202   [0x7fff89cf14f3]
>   - !           : | + !       : | + ! : | + 90 -[Connection _fillBuffer:]  (in CoreMessage) + 764  [0x7fff89cf1961]
>   - !           : | + !       : | + ! : | +   90 -[Connection _readBytesFromSocketIntoBuffer:amount:requireAllBytes:error:]   (in CoreMessage) + 76  [0x7fff89cf1a7b]
>   - !           : | + !       : | + ! : | +     89 -[_NSSocket readBytes:length:error:]  (in CoreMessage) + 161   [0x7fff89cd78cb]
>   - !           : | + !       : | + ! : | +     ! 50 _handleRequestWithTimeout  (in CoreMessage) + 1717  [0x7fff89cd51a7]
>   - !           : | + !       : | + ! : | +     ! : 44 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) _removePort:forMode:]  (in Foundation) + 460   [0x7fff8eb4513d]
>   - !           : | + !       : | + ! : | +     ! : | 40 ???  (in Mail)

load address 0x1024e3000 + 0x45ff  [0x1024e75ff]

Also, the Activity (in Mail I think) window shows that these lines: 
Inbox/updating cache directory ; Fetching new mail ; Synchronizing with server/Getting unread counts ; Communicating with server/Inbox fetching
all end up with a red "stop sign" at the end.

He seems to have the latest version of Mail, so we can't update it, and he doesn't want to properly uninstall/reinstall the Mail program.

Connection Doctor shows that:

- SMTP: Connection to server succeeded; login not required.
- IMAP: Connection and login to server succeeded.

The details (with important information marked as " XXXXXX "), I hope this helps:

> INITIATING CONNECTION Jul 30 10:27:43.844 -- host:XXXXXX(smtp) --
>   port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x0 -- thread:0x7fd41b4a2770
>
> INITIATING CONNECTION Jul 30 10:27:43.844 -- host:XXXXXX(imap) --
>   port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x0 -- thread:0x7fd41b26a590
>
> CONNECTED Jul 30 10:27:43.874 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNone] --
>   host:XXXXXX(smtp) -- port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x7fd41d9bd920
>   -- thread:0x7fd41b4a2770
>
> CONNECTED Jul 30 10:27:43.875 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNone] --
>   host:XXXXXX(imap) -- port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x7fd41d8b2bd0
>   -- thread:0x7fd41b26a590
>
> READ Jul 30 10:27:43.892 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNone] --
>   host:XXXXXX(imap) -- port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x7fd41d8b2bd0 --
>   thread:0x7fd41b26a590
>
> - OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Mail Server ready.
>
> WROTE Jul 30 10:27:43.898 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNone] --
>   host:XXXXXX(imap) -- port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x7fd41d8b2bd0 --
>   thread:0x7fd41b177030
>   1.12 STARTTLS
>
> READ Jul 30 10:27:43.912 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNone] --
>   host:XXXXXX(imap) -- port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x7fd41d8b2bd0 --
>   thread:0x7fd41b177030
>   1.12 OK Begin TLS negotiation now.
>
> READ Jul 30 10:27:43.971 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNone] --
>   host:XXXXXX(smtp) -- port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x7fd41d9bd920 --
>   thread:0x7fd41b4a2770 220 XXXXXX(imap) ESMTP
>
> WROTE Jul 30 10:27:43.980 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1SSLv3] --
>   host:XXXXXX(imap) -- port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x7fd41d8b2bd0 --
>   thread:0x7fd41daaff00
>   2.12 CAPABILITY
>
> WROTE Jul 30 10:27:43.992 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNone] --
>   host:XXXXXX(smtp) -- port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x7fd41d9bd920 --
>   thread:0x7fd41b4a2770 EHLO [XXXXXX(IP)]
>
> READ Jul 30 10:27:43.995 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1SSLv3] --
>   host:XXXXXX(imap) -- port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x7fd41d8b2bd0
>   -- thread:0x7fd41daaff00
>
> - CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE SORT SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=REFS MULTIAPPEND UNSELECT IDLE
>     CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 CONDSTORE QRESYNC
>     ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH LIST-STATUS QUOTA
>     AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN
>     2.12 OK Capability completed.
>
> READ Jul 30 10:27:44.013 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNone] --
>   host:XXXXXX(smtp) -- port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x7fd41d9bd920 --
>   thread:0x7fd41b4a2770 250-XXXXXX(imap) 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE
>   20480000 250-VRFY 250-ETRN 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
>   250-8BITMIME 250 DSN
>
> WROTE Jul 30 10:27:44.019 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1SSLv3] --
>   host:XXXXXX(imap) -- port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x7fd41d8b2bd0 --
>   thread:0x7fd41dbb57f0
>   3.12 ID ("name" "Mac OS X Mail" "version" "6.5 (1508)" "os" "Mac OS X" "os-version" "10.8.4 (12E55)" "vendor" "Apple Inc.") WROTE Jul 30
>   10:27:44.028 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNone] -- host:XXXXXX(smtp)
>   -- port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x7fd41d9bd920 -- thread:0x7fd41b4a2770 QUIT
>
> READ Jul 30 10:27:44.045 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1SSLv3] --
>   host:XXXXXX(imap) -- port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x7fd41d8b2bd0
>   -- thread:0x7fd41dbb57f0
>   * ID NIL
>   3.12 OK ID completed. WROTE Jul 30 10:27:44.065 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1SSLv3] -- host:XXXXXX(imap) --
>   port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x7fd41d8b2bd0 -- thread:0x7fd41dbb57f0
>   4.12 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN ********************
>
> READ Jul 30 10:27:44.082 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1SSLv3] --
>   host:XXXXXX(imap) -- port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x7fd41d8b2bd0
>   -- thread:0x7fd41dbb57f0
>   4.12 OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE SORT SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=REFS MULTIAPPEND
>   UNSELECT IDLE CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1
>   CONDSTORE QRESYNC ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH
>   LIST-STATUS QUOTA] Logged in WROTE Jul 30 10:27:44.099
>   [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1SSLv3] -- host:XXXXXX(imap) --
>   port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x7fd41d8b2bd0 -- thread:0x7fd41b4fbf80
>   5.12 LIST "" "" READ Jul 30 10:27:44.130 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1SSLv3] -- host:XXXXXX(imap) --
>   port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x7fd41d8b2bd0
>   -- thread:0x7fd41b4fbf80
>   * LIST (\Noselect) "." ""
>   5.12 OK List completed. WROTE Jul 30 10:27:44.150 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1SSLv3] -- host:XXXXXX(imap) --
>   port:XXXXXX -- socket:0x7fd41d8b2bd0 -- thread:0x7fd41b4a2770
>   6.12 LOGOUT

Please, if you have any idea on what we could do.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the editing, Buscar. I had some trouble with some parts (the logs).